# case when on inner join

Tags: sql-server, case, inner-join

I have the following 4 tables:  MainTable, Warehouse,Customer and Company.

The schema of these tables:

```
create table MainTable(ID int, Warehouse_id int, Customer_ID int)
create table Warehouse (Warehouse_id int, company_id int)
create table Customer (Customer_ID int, Company_ID int)
create table company (Company_id int, Country_ID int, Zone_ID int)
```

The objectif is to get the  Country_ID and Zone_ID  for the corresponding ID (of MainTable).

We have 2 different cases: `if MainTable.Warehouse_ID` is not null we should do the inner join on Warehouse table (on field warehouse_id) and then a join on Company table (on field Company_ID),
`else` (if  MainTable.Warehouse_ID is null) we should do the inner join on Customer Table (on Customer_ID field) and then on Company Table (on Company_ID field).

the following query generates an error near the word 'case':

```
select CO.Country_ID, CO.Zone_ID
from    MainTable MT 
inner join (case 
    when MT.Warehouse_ID is not null 
then
         Warehouse W on MT.Warehouse_ID=W.Warehouse_ID 
        inner join Company CO on W.Company_ID=CO.Company_ID
else     
         Customer Cu on MT.Customer_ID=Cu.Customer_ID
        inner join Company C on Cu.Company_ID=CO.Company_ID
    end)
```

Am I doing this right with a small syntax error that i missed? If not..is there any other way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: one way to do it, is by dynamic query! but you will need to use a stored proc for it

Comment: Dynamic SQL won't help since the condition is specific to each line

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx):

```
SELECT CO.Country_ID, CO.Zone_ID
  FROM MainTable MT
  INNER JOIN Warehouse W ON MT.Warehouse_ID=W.Warehouse_ID
  INNER JOIN Company CO on W.Company_ID=CO.Company_ID
  WHERE MT.Warehouse_ID IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT CO.Country_ID, CO.Zone_ID
  FROM MainTable MT
  INNER JOIN Customer Cu ON MT.Customer_ID=Cu.Customer_ID
  INNER JOIN Company CO on Cu.Company_ID=CO.Company_ID
  WHERE MT.Warehouse_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something as below:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
          FROM   MainTable mt
          WHERE  mt.Warehouse_ID IS NOT NULL)
  BEGIN
      SELECT CO.Country_ID,
             CO.Zone_ID
      FROM   MainTable MT
             INNER JOIN Warehouse W
                     ON MT.Warehouse_ID = W.Warehouse_ID
             INNER JOIN Company CO
                     ON W.Company_ID = CO.Company_ID
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
      SELECT CO.Country_ID,
             CO.Zone_ID
      FROM   MainTable MT
             INNER JOIN Customer Cu
                     ON MT.Customer_ID = Cu.Customer_ID
             INNER JOIN Company C
                     ON Cu.Company_ID = CO.Company_ID
  END
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that. **What would you expect the output to be** with this kind of conditional joins ?

Have you tried using outer joins ?

```
select ISNULL(C1.Country_ID,C2.Country_ID) as Country_ID,ISNULL(C1.Zone_ID,C2.Zone_ID) as Zone_ID
from    MainTable MT 
left outer join  Warehouse W on MT.Warehouse_ID=W.Warehouse_ID 
left outer join Company1 C1 on W.Company_ID=C1.Company_ID
left outer join Customer Cu on MT.Customer_ID=Cu.Customer_ID
left outer join Company2 C2 on Cu.Company_ID=C2.Company_ID
```

Comment: for what the minus please ?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Thomas, with left outer join it works :)